# With REST PUT command, In the input body, lines starting with # are ignored. would like to know why?

Tags: rest, put

I make REST Call, PUT command. As input to the PUT command in the body, I have lines that starts with #. Such lines are silently ignored and don't come as part of input.

Can anybody please explain why ?

Comment: What `Content-Type` does this body have? What does the REST service consume?

Comment: content-type is application/xml

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include XML with such lines? And please also include the code (which language?) you use to parse this XML.